# How to import and show a HTML file in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to show a HTML file generated by `animation:saveHTML` in the `mainPanel` of `Shiny`. I am aware that the HTML file has a few dependent files, so I tried to put them all into the directory of the `ui.R` and `server.R`. And just to test it in `ui.R` using `includeHTML(XXX.html)`, but it shows nothing.

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is I have two buttons, 1st one is just a plotting button for the `mainPanel` and the 2nd button is for showing the HTML file in the same Panel.

I have another button for generating the animation HTML files, and it works fine. The plan is that the user has to click the HTML generating button first, then press showHTML button to see the animation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [embed iframe inside shiny app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020558/embed-iframe-inside-shiny-app)