# Shiny Iframe not showing any website

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I am trying show a iframe with a website in shiny, but it is always showing blank page.

Below is the code taken from a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020558/embed-iframe-inside-shiny-app)

Code:

```
 rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
members <- data.frame(name=c("Name 1", "Name 2"), nr=c('BCRA1','FITM2'))

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Getting Iframe"), 

                  mainPanel(fluidRow(
                    htmlOutput("my_test")
                  )
                  )
                )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_test <- renderUI({
     tags$iframe(src='https://www.google.co.in/', height=600, width=535)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output:
[image]
Why am I not able to show any website.  Please help me, I google a lot and tried many options including the renderUI; htmloutput and uioutput panels.

Comment: I can confirm that both your example or the example in the linked questions show a blank iframe. The javascript console gives me the error `Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` in both cases. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe) for more reference.

Comment: Thank you @GregordeCillia -  I checked a local web server and it working. Google is a common site tot check with in general so did not check other sites earlier. Please submit it as an answer -  I will mark it complete; but R console did not throw it as an error. How can I know such cases?

Comment: I just postet an answer and included a keyboard shortcut for acessing the JavaScript console. Quite a few error messages in JavaScript are not returned to R by shiny so I would suggest to check this console every now and then to keep your apps stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem you are facing is that the site you were referencing to had the `X-Frame-Options` set to `sameorigin`. This means that `iframes` are basically blocked by the `https://www.google.co.in` server.

You can see a corresponding error message in the javascript console which can be acessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in google chrome. For other browsers see [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Certain workarounds and morde discussion about the `X-Frame-Options` issue can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe).

Comment: looking for the R workaround for this