# R Shiny ensuring pdf scales to iframe size

Tags: r, pdf, iframe, shiny

I've been working to embed a pdf from a local drive into a shiny app. The .pdf file is in the www folder and it has been embedded into an iframe.

The code for the UI is

```
              tabPanel("How This Model Was Generated",
                       tags$iframe(height="1000px",
                                   width="100%",
                                   scrolling=T,
                                   src="Win Prob Explanation.pdf")
                       )
```

The iframe is the right size, the .pdf is importing into the webApp, and it deploys fine. Those aren't the problem. The problem is that it looks like this: [iframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz4DK.png)
I can zoom in and it reads completely fine, so it's not the image/.pdf quality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020558/embed-iframe-inside-shiny-app This may help

Comment: The issue isn't that the iframe isn't embedding. It is. The issue is that the image inside the frame isn't scaling to fill it out or even scaling to its default size