# R Shiny WebApp & R Shiny Dashboard menuItem - How to make them Dynamically link to other URL

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to make the `menuItem` option on my sidebar a URL Link. 
I still want to keep it as a `menuItem` but am trying to embed it into a URL. Perhaps you guys can help.

Example:

```
## Sidebar content
dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
    menuItem("Reports", tabName = "reports", icon = icon("th")),
    menuItem("OpsCare Clients", tabName = "OpsCare Clients", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
    menuItem("ProdCare Clients", tabName = "ProdCare Clients", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
    menuItem("Alerts", tabName = "Alerts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
    menuItem("Change Requests", tabName = "Change Requests", icon = icon("list-alt")),
    menuItem("Maintenance Windows", tabName = "Maintenance Windows", icon = icon("list-alt")),
    menuItem("Rundeck", tabName = "Rundeck", icon = icon("bars")),
    menuItem("Salesforce", tabName = "Salesforce", icon = icon("bars")),
    menuItem("Handovers", tabName = "Handovers", icon = icon("bars")),
    menuItem("Jump-Host Access", tabName = "Jump-Host Access", icon = icon("bars"))
  )
)
```

),

From the above you can see the menuItem labeled as Salesforce. I would like this to Link back up to my Salesforce login page.

Kind Regards,
Richard Barrett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you do not have to use tag$iframe to make a dashboard side menu item dynamically link to another page. Instead you can just use the href. Example is below:

```
menuItem("Source code", icon = icon("github"), href = "https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/Miradashboard")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tags$iframe` for this.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021018/7665276).

Comment: Thanks Rituraj :D, much appreciated!

Comment: So it turns out I didn't even need the tag$ifram, you just have to use "href" within the menuItem and drop the tabName.

Comment: @R.Barrett is right. You can't have tabName and href at the same time