# How to embed facebook post in shiny r?

Tags: r, facebook, shiny, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use the [facebook SKD](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/?prefill_href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fladygaga%2Fposts%2F10157645664974574#code-generator) to embed a post in my Shiny app. I have the iframe of a public post.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fladygaga%2Fposts%2F10157645664974574&width=500" width="500" height="594" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Currently I'm using the shiny HTML() function and I managed to see the fb_iframe_widget in the developer console. But the post is not showing.

[image]

This is what my current approach looks like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
HTML('<div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3"></script>')

HTML('<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php? href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fladygaga%2Fposts%2F10157645664974574&width=500" width="500" height="594" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>')
))
```

I also tried doing what they do here: [embed iframe inside shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020558/embed-iframe-inside-shiny-app)

It didn't work. I get the iframe but not the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes work perfectly fine. But you need to open the app in a separate browser. Iframe doesn't work in Rstudio Viewer Pane.

[image]