# datatable doesn't render in rmarkdown inside shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

I've got a an Rmarkdown file I want to display inside a shiny app, along with a download button to download it. Most of this works fine, but I've got a `DT::datatable` inside the Rmarkdown document. The datatable renders fine in the Rmarkdown once you download and open it, but the table doesn't show up inside the shiny app itself.

Is there a way I can get the datatable to show up inside the app as well? I don't want to use kable etc. because the download and filtering options with datatable are really useful.

Rmarkdown ("report.Rmd"):

````
---
title: "Example report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```

A plot of `params$n` random points.

```{r plot1}
plot(rnorm(params$n), rnorm(params$n))
```

```{r table1}
DT::datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE, 
                colnames = c("Sepal length", "Sepal width", "Petal length", "Petal width", "Species"), 
                extensions = 'Buttons',
                filter = "none",
                options = list(pageLength = 25, autowidth = TRUE,
                           dom = 'Blftip',                           
                           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')))
```
````

Shiny app:

```
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
        actionButton("generate_report", "Generate report")
        ),
        mainPanel(uiOutput("report"))
    )),
    server = function(input, output) {
    
        observeEvent(input$slider, {
            output$report <- renderUI(textOutput("holding_text"))
        })
        
        output$holding_text <- renderText("Please select inputs and click 'Generate report'")
        
        observeEvent(input$generate_report, {

            # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it
            my_temp <- tempdir()
            
            tempReport <- file.path(my_temp, "report.Rmd")
            file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
            
            # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
            params <- list(n = input$slider)
            
            # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
            # child of the global environment
            rmarkdown::render(tempReport,
                              params = params,
                              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
            )
            output$report <- renderUI({
                tagList(
                    downloadButton("download", "Download report"),
                    htmltools::HTML(includeHTML(file.path(my_temp, "report.html")))
                    
                )
            })
            
            output$download <- downloadHandler(
                # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
                filename = "report.html",
                content = function(file) {
                    file.copy(file.path(my_temp, "report.html"), file)
                }
            )
        })
        
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Shiny doesn't execute JS when you call includeHTML, and DT needs it to render the tables.

There are 2 options:

1. Include you file with the iframe tag (details here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021018/17518257), but it has some disadvantages (default height and width not always properly calculated, scroll issues, etc.).
2. Render your DT directly in Shiny, which I find much cleaner. The disadvantage is that the report is now in 2 parts, the datatables and the rest. Here's how to do it.

First, store your DT in a variable before displaying it in the .Rmd file:

````
```{r table1}
dt_iris <- DT::datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE, 
                colnames = c("Sepal length", "Sepal width", "Petal length", "Petal width", "Species"), 
                extensions = 'Buttons',
                filter = "none",
                options = list(pageLength = 25, autowidth = TRUE,
                           dom = 'Blftip',                           
                           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')))
dt_iris
```
````

Then, create you render environment for your Markdown before the  render() call, to access the variable dt_iris later:

```
env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
rmarkdown::render(tempReport,
                              params = params,
                              envir = env)
dt_iris <- env$dt_iris
```

Finally, display dt_iris with renderUI() and uiOutput():

```
ui <- fluidPage(
mainPanel(uiOutput("report"), uiOutput('dt'))

server <- function(input, output) {
output$report <- renderUI({
                tagList(
                    downloadButton("download", "Download report"),
                    htmltools::HTML(includeHTML(file.path(my_temp, "report.html")))
                    
                )
            })
output$dt <- renderUI({
                    htmltools::tagList(dt_iris)
                })
}
```